# Unable to replace url from string content org.apache.pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, processing, pdfbox

I have one pdf file that have lot of links inside pdf, But those not annoted properly, And my organization going to release new website, So I want to collect all links from old domain and want to replace with new domain

Tried this code to collect all links from pdf

```
public void parsePdf(final Path path) {
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
        for (PDPage pdPage : document.getPages()) {
            pdPage.getAnnotations()
                .stream()
                .filter(annotation -> annotation instanceof PDAnnotationLink)
                .map(annotation -> (PDAnnotationLink) annotation)
                .map(PDAnnotationLink::getAction)
                .filter(action -> action instanceof PDActionURI)
                .forEach(action -> {
                    System.out.println(((PDActionURI) action).getURI());
                    }
                );
        }
        document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        document.save(path.toFile());
    }
}
```

I am unable to collect any link, I tried with TextStrip it works to retrieve link

```
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(Path.of(path.toString()).toFile());
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        textStripper.setLineSeparator("\n");

        String textContent = textStripper.getText(document);

        // Use regular expression to find URLs in the text content, accounting for multi-line URLs
        String urlRegex = "(?:http[s]?://|www\\.)[\\S\\n]+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textContent);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String url = matcher.group().replaceAll("\\n", ""); // Remove line breaks from the matched URL
            System.out.println(url);
            textContent.replaceAll(url,"test.com");
        }
```

But not able to update that location. Some of the links pattern to detect because somewhere added '\n' or space.

My pdf contains images as well, So I dont want to loose anything, So is there any way to detect and repalce the link which is not annoted.

Maven Dependency

```js
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
   <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Feel free to comment any input required from my side and ofcourse thank you !

Comment: fwiw I just used your code on a libreoffice Writer doc that I exported to pdf. It printed out the targets of the links just fine

Comment: Oh right. I think I might have misunderstood. If they are not 'proper' links then surely that code can't possibly work?

Comment: I have bad space somewhere, and some place i have normal string but that is link @KJ

Comment: You can check this pdf for example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OqLjSUXpJ1Z3Ap5uDhSXMr0IdG9R6hCO/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I am ok with any language, but i have thousands of pdf that i need to convert, via pattern i am able to detect that but unable to update in pdf, because not aware about the location, if someone from pdfbox give some info then it would be great

Comment: As @KJ said, the linked document simply contains links in the footnote plain text. Those are going to be quite tricky to parse out with regex such that they will be valid links because they cross line boundaries

Comment: @KJ Manual changes is not possible, I have lot of pdf with me. Whatever you edited that i expect from coding

Comment: This is the sort of problem you face: `https://$www.sec.gov/news/speech/spch120604rjc.htm$3` where I mark the line breaks by `$`. Multiline matching will give you the www joined correctly, but will *in* correctly give you the '3' (which is there to denote a new bulletpoint in the footnotes) joined on to the url. Endings of urls are super-arbitrary and can contain mostly anything apart from the space character

Comment: *but I think that specific was not a great problem that actual entry works as www.sec.gov/news/speech/spch120604rjc.htm* Well, you and I know what the link *should* be, but the machine doesn't and the fact is that it *is broken*. That just happens to be the first one I noticed as problematic. Then you've got the problem (especially with old documents) that even when the machine gets it right, some links will be broken

Comment: I am worried about accoutingresearchmanger.com related urls @KJ

Comment: I have lot of links, I just shared one pdf, mostly you can focus on accounting* related urls @g00se

Comment: Can we read para to para and can able to replace para to para? if Yes then we can add custom logic, Somehow to achieve this task, But i dont want to loose formatting and images

Comment: This task can only be partially automated. All the broken links are going to have to be given to a *person* to sort out

Comment: There will undoubtedly be lots of application-specific ops related to urls. The relevant thing here is that specific api sees *no links* in that document so effectively they are plain text. No automation would be necessary at all, presumably, if they all worked

Comment: I dont have common same url at one place, based on url, I want to caluclate id and new domain have different id, so that id i can pick from server and create new url

Comment: I just had a look at the document and have to confirm what KJ and g00se  already said - the URLs are not marked as such in any way, neither using tags nor by special styles. There is no clear way to automatically determine where the URL ends. But I think it would be possible to implement an URL editor working for this and very similar documents (as long as the replacement URLs are not longer in print than the current ones). But you say you have thousands of documents to edit. If they are similar (not only on screen but also internally) to your example, creating such an editor may make sense.

Comment: But even then you should have someone verifying the outputs unless a certain error rate is acceptable.

Comment: and I saw above code not work for footer link replacement