# Unable to replace text from footer pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am going to replace link and text from pdf, for this using itext library. Sometime hyperlink uri replaces but text not updated and sometime both not work

Maven dependency

```
        <itextpdf.version>5.5.13.3</itextpdf.version>
        <bcprov-jdk15on.version>1.69</bcprov-jdk15on.version>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itextpdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>${bcprov-jdk15on.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java code:

```
public void parsePdf(final Path path) {
        try {
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile("_pdfwriting", ".pdf");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Files.newInputStream(path));
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(tempPath.toFile()));

            int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
                PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
                PdfArray annotsArray = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
                if (annotsArray != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.size(); j++) {
                        PdfDictionary annotDict = annotsArray.getAsDict(j);
                        if (annotDict != null && PdfName.LINK.equals(annotDict.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                            PdfDictionary actionDict = annotDict.getAsDict(PdfName.A);
                            if (actionDict != null && PdfName.URI.equals(actionDict.getAsName(PdfName.S))) {
                                PdfString uri = actionDict.getAsString(PdfName.URI);
                                if (uri != null) {
                                    PdfString newUri = new PdfString("New url");
                                    PdfString newText = new PdfString("New text");
                                    actionDict.put(PdfName.URI, newUri);
                                    actionDict.put(PdfName.T, newText);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            stamper.close();
            reader.close();

            Files.copy(tempPath, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.deleteIfExists(tempPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For sample you can check this pdf : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10RL39EKxB-f91PvdoWFQTmEs9-3SU-SK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Q:  Have you stepped through the debugger to verify you ever enter the block `if (uri != null) {}`?  Have you checked the URIs you're getting?  Q: Does your "stamper" output file look OK otherwise?

Comment: Not updated hyperlink in this file, but I checked other file there hyperlink updated but text not replaced. Beheviour different across the pdf files

Comment: Please update your post and clarify exactly what the problem is.  For example: "I'm trying to update the text and hyperlink in the footer, but sometimes only the link is updated, not the text.  Other times, both are updated correctly.  Still other times, neither are updated."

Comment: See [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134840813?noredirect=1)

Comment: If this still is about the same task as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76458772/1729265), you're out of luck. The *links* pdf libraries allow you to find easily are *link annotations* while your example PDF only contains some URL in the regular, static page text.

Comment: Hi @KJ, Could you share the code, So I can see where its update ?